# append same Series to data frame columns

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have the following dataframe:

```
data=pd.DataFrame(data=[[8,4,2,6,0],[3,4,5,6,7]],columns=["a","b","c","d","e"])
```

Output is like this:

```
    a b c d e
0   8 4 2 6 0
1   3 4 5 6 7
```

I also have the following Series:

```
a=pd.Series([3,4])
```

I want to attach the series (a) to each of the columns in data. I tried few things with concat but I never seem to get it right.

Expected result is:

```
    a b c d e
0   8 4 2 6 0
1   3 4 5 6 7
2   3 3 3 3 3
3   4 4 4 4 4
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `pandas.DataFrame.apply`

with `pandas.Series.append`
I like this because it's pretty

```
data.apply(pd.Series.append, to_append=a, ignore_index=True)

   a  b  c  d  e
0  8  4  2  6  0
1  3  4  5  6  7
2  3  3  3  3  3
3  4  4  4  4  4
```

A golfier answer

```
data.apply(pd.Series.append, args=(a, 1))
```

---

#### `numpy.row_stack`

Very similar to [rafaelc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57501643/2336654)

```
pd.DataFrame(np.row_stack([
    data,
    a.to_numpy()[:, None].repeat(data.shape[1], axis=1)
]), columns=data.columns)

   a  b  c  d  e
0  8  4  2  6  0
1  3  4  5  6  7
2  3  3  3  3  3
3  4  4  4  4  4
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
out=data.append(pd.concat([a]*data.shape[1],axis=1,keys=data.columns),ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  8  4  2  6  0
1  3  4  5  6  7
2  3  3  3  3  3
3  4  4  4  4  4
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method from for loop

```
for x ,y in a.iteritems(): 
    data.loc[data.index[-1]+x+1]=y

data
Out[106]: 
   a  b  c  d  e
0  8  4  2  6  0
1  3  4  5  6  7
2  3  3  3  3  3
4  4  4  4  4  4
```

Comment: `data.loc[len(data)] = y` might be simpler ;p

Answer (score 2):

Using `broadcast_to`

```
df.append(pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(a.to_frame(), (len(a), df.shape[1])), columns=df.columns), ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  8  4  2  6  0
1  3  4  5  6  7
2  3  3  3  3  3
3  4  4  4  4  4
```